# Unable to filter Cucumber Feature files while running them with JUNIT5

Tags: java, gradle, cucumber, junit5, cucumber-java

I'm able to run cucumber feature files in parallel with combination cucumber+JUnit5+Gradle. But unable to filter feature files which needs to be run;

My feature files are located under resource folder at path "com.automation.runners" . And, @Cucumber class is also located at the package name but under java folder;
With this configuration I am able run all feature files but I want run only one feature file.

I have an entry cucumber.features=com/automation/runners/Demo.feature in "junit-platform.properties". But this solution is not working for me. Please help me!!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [documentation for the Cucumber Junit 5 integration](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine) you'll see that `cucumber.features` is not listed as one of the supported properties. And if you read the [Java doc on @Cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/junit-platform-engine/src/main/java/io/cucumber/junit/platform/engine/Cucumber.java):

```java
 * Some build tools do not support the
 * {@link org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectors} used by
 * Cucumber. As a work around Cucumber will scan the package of the annotated
 * class for feature files and execute them.
```

So it is to be expected that all your features are executed.

To run a single feature you can use the [Console Launcher](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher) with `--select-file` or the [JUnit Platform Launcher API](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api). For both you can use [the supported selectors](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine#supported-discovery-selectors-and-filters).

```java
package com.example;

import org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectors;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.LauncherDiscoveryRequest;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory;

public class RunSingleFile {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();
        LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
                .selectors(DiscoverySelectors.selectFile("path/to/my.feature"))
                .build();
        launcher.execute(request);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Korstanje for your help!